# Draw line after path

Tags: keyframes, path

I am making a tutorial for billard and i am trying to make an animation showing the path a ball will take. Over my 3D model i have imported a picture of the line i want to animate. My question is, how do i efficiently draw and animate this line? I just want the line to be flat and smooth. Current attempts include making a path or Bezier curve and then use the bevel feature, but here I am not sure how to avoid the line curving because it automatically interpolates between points, and when i find a workaround the corners just looks odd. Also, the bevel feature does not seem to allow me to make a flat line, but instead a cylinder, which i then had to press flat, which might be why the corners look odd.

[image: the lines is want to draw]

The lines i want to draw

[image: the corners i think look odd]

The corners i think looks odd

[image: how it looks currently]

How it looks currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar in the past, although I was looking for rounded bezier paths and I came up with this, which works - somehow - also when lines are straight, and not rounded. I'm not sure if it helps you but at least it's done differently, as it does not use bevel but an animated array modifier plus a curve modifier...

this is the setup: the bezier segments iirc have been straightened using: V => vector first, and then V => free.

I also exaggerated the line width (editing the small rectangle in edit mode) to better show it in pictures here.

[image]

and this is the animation that is produced:

[image]

I'm not sure if it solves your corners issues...

Here's the file, anyway.
[image]